# Matlab openfig from URL or java input stream

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm using WebFigures in Matlab and calling the getFig function from Java

```
function df = getFig(file)

  f = openfig(file,'new','invisible');

  figure('Visible','Off')

  df = webfigure(f);
  close(f);
end
```

This above works when passing a string to a path location, however not when using a URL. Is it possible to in Java load the file from the URL and then pass it as some kind of inputstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I just had to download the file using Java and pass in the location to matlab

Answer (score 0):

OPENFIG works only with local files. Try to use [URLWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/urlwrite.html) to download the file to some temporary location and then OPENFIG to open that file.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought that as a possible solution, but worried about performance implications.